# How can I remove js of disabled extensions in my js bundle?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2.2.2

I am not very deep into Magento, so I might just have missed something.
I am using the JS Bundling feature, and I've read there are quite some issues. As with many other people, the resulting bundle is huge.

I realize that it loads all scripts on every page. But I've noticed something else:
In my bundled js file I see JS Components loaded from e.g. "Temando_Shipping" - even though that plugin is disabled in my store.

How can that be? And how can I disable those plugins js being loaded?

Comment: Does Temando_Shipping show as disabled? (module:status)
Did you manualy clean static files and did a php/bin mangeto static-content:deploy after disabling the module?

Comment: Temando_Shipping does show as disabled, and I did run static-content:deploy. Not sure about manually cleaning the static files. I'll give that a try.